# Can not retrieve post value from a form

Tags: php, forms

In page test.php I have a form something like

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">   

<a href="test.php?id=5" name="test_name1">click me</a> 
<a href="test.php?id=5" name="test_name2">click me</a>
<a href="test.php?id=5" name="test_name3">click me</a>

</form>
```

And if someone click on those links then i have to check something like

```
if (isset($_POST['test_name1'])) {  

    //do my work
}
```

But this is not working for me. I have to check for all the links and that form has about 10 such links. Please help

Comment: Links do not submit forms, so the POST is never sent.

Comment: Huh? Why are you using those links in that case instead of some hidden input fields or whatever fields? P.S. to the people who upvoted this I would really like to know your reasoning please???

Comment: you mean you want check box

Answer (score 1):

That's not how forms work. You have a `GET` link inside a `POST` form.

Sample `POST` (`script.php`):

```
<?php

  if( isset($_POST[submit]) ) {
     //do
  }

?>

<form method="post" action="script.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Sample `GET` (`script2.php`):

```
<?php

  if( isset($_GET[id]) ) {
    //do
  }

?>

<a href="script2.php?id=2">Click me</a>
```

This might be more of what you're trying to accomplish (`script3.php`):

```
<?php

  if( isset($_GET[id]) && isset($_GET[name]) ) {
    //do
  }

?>

<a href="script3.php?id=5&name=test_name1">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you want check box you can try like

```
<form   method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">value one<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">value tow<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3">value three<br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check;  
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**$_POST** methods are only for ***FORM*** elements not for ***Anchor*** Element. But in your case, you have ***Anchor*** element linked to php file. You can check ***isset*** for id but not for the ***Anchor*** element name. ***id*** will also be checked by:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a link as a form parameter... what you could do is make hidden values and have three different forms. Although this method use buttons data transferred is less obvious to the user when using $_POST instead of $_GET which shows the data in the link.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
<input type="input" name="test_name1">
</form>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
<input type="input" name="test_name2">
</form>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
<input type="input" name="test_name3">
</form>
```

Then at the top of your page you can check for...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test_name1'])){
//they clicked button 1.
}
?>
```

If you want to get data from using only a link you could do this and retrieve the data with $_GET...

```
<a href="test.php?id=5">click me</a>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']){
//they clicked your link.
}
?>
```